# How do I obtain the Maximum Number of Jumps?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I was recently asked the following simple question during one of the coding interviews:

You are given an integer array "numbers" and some difference "diff" as your inputs.

You can jump to the next square (or index) as long as these conditions are satisfied:

```py
i != j
numbers[i] == numbers[j]
```

The absolute difference between indices are less than or equal to "diff", `abs(i-j) <= diff`.

Find the maximum number of squares in that particular array.

Although, it is unsatisfying in terms of time complexity, I came up with solution below for the sake of time constraints. However, it does not give the correct answer most of the time.

Is there anyone who can point out the flaws in my solution?

Thanks in advance.

```py
def count_jump(numbers, diff):
    index_dict = dict()

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if numbers[i] not in index_dict:
            index_dict[numbers[i]] = []
        index_dict[numbers[i]].append(i)

    max_ = 0
    for item in index_dict:
        result = 0
        i = 0
        for j in index_dict[item]:
            if i != j and numbers[i] == numbers[j] and abs(i-j) <= diff:
                i = j
                result+=1
        max_ = max(max_, result)

    return max_+1

a = [1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2]
print(count_jump(a, 3))
```

For the example above, the maximum number of squares that we can jump is `4`. Start from index `0`, jump to index `2`, and then to `5`, and then to `6`.

Comment: But in your example   5-2>diff=2

Comment: you are right @MBo, I corrected it

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, assigning the variable "i" to 0 each and every time was a mistake. Instead, it should be assigned to the first index of the item that we are investigating.
Since we do not have to include each square with the same value, i.e we can discard the first element if it is too far away from other values, the result should be set to 0 after each dissatisfaction of the condition.

```
max_ = 0
for item in index_dict:
    result = 0
    i = index_dict[item][0]
    for j in index_dict[item]:
        if i != j and abs(i-j) <= diff:
            result+=1
            max_ = max(max_, result)
        else:
            result = 0
        i = j
```

Comment: Seems you need to move `max` finding after `result+=1`. Also `numbers[i] == numbers[j]` is not needed because list contains indices for  one value only